# If a dual France-US citizen gets drafted by both France and the US in the event of a war, must the individual join the French or the US army?

Tags: us-citizens, dual-citizenship, french-citizens

If a dual France-US citizen gets drafted by both France and the US in the event of a war, must the individual join the French or the US army?

If both, can they avoid getting fined/jailed/punished for not joining one of the two armies?

Assume the individual is a male [if that matters](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Conscription&oldid=960993686#United_States).

---

https://www.vie-publique.fr/fiches/23908-quen-est-il-du-devoir-de-defense (government website) indicates that France has a military draft in case of war:

> Depuis la levée en masse des Français de 1792, afin de défendre "la Patrie en danger" et de renforcer l’armée française, le devoir de défense du territoire est lié à la citoyenneté. Tout Français de sexe masculin est donc susceptible d’être mobilisé afin de défendre le territoire national, ou, plus largement, de se battre pour son pays (y compris sur un théâtre d’opération extérieur à la France).

[GTranslate](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20558/if-a-dual-france-us-citizen-gets-drafted-by-both-france-and-the-us-in-the-event?noredirect=1#comment33254_20558):

> Since the mass levy of the French in 1792, in order to defend "the Fatherland in danger" and to strengthen the French army, the duty to defend the territory has been linked to citizenship. Any French man is therefore likely to be mobilized in order to defend the national territory, or, more generally, to fight for his country (including in a theater of operation outside France).

http://www.forum-militaire.fr/topic/7973-si-guerre-oblig%C3%A9-daller-combattre/

> Si guerre, obligé d'aller combattre ? Oui tu seras réquisitionné car tes devoirs de citoyens t'obligent à défendre ton pays et ses valeurs.

[GTranslate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=en&text=Si%20guerre%2C%20oblig%C3%A9%20d'aller%20combattre%20%3F%20Oui%20tu%20seras%20r%C3%A9quisitionn%C3%A9%20car%20tes%20devoirs%20de%20citoyens%20t'obligent%20%C3%A0%20d%C3%A9fendre%20ton%20pays%20et%20ses%20valeurs.):

> If war, forced to go to fight? Yes, you will be requisitioned because your duties as citizens oblige you to defend your country and its values.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I've added a quote that claims France has a military draft in case of war.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica https://www.vie-publique.fr/fiches/23908-quen-est-il-du-devoir-de-defense (government website) confirms that France has a military draft in case of war.

Comment: That's a much more persuasive source, thanks. So France does indeed have a statutory draft, although it it not now being exercised or enforced. That satisfies my objection d), but still leaves a), b), and c) in place. I still think the original question will generate only opinion-based and speculative answers.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica a) and c) are irrelevant because the situation of interest is being drafted. Doesn't matter for what kind of war. b) that should be an answer, not a reason to close.

Comment: We can differ. I guess we'll see if others' views agree with yours or with mine.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica ok but if this gets closed and I later get into trouble during ww3, you give me a discount on your attorney fees ;)

Comment: I tried real hard to add "<g>" as a response, but the system won't let me.

Comment: @DavidSuppprtsMonica the US absolutely does have a draft. Although the US is not currently exercising its statutory authority to induct men into the military against their will, it does require men between the ages of 18 and 26 to register.  See https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/50/chapter-49.  This has been the case since the Soviet Union invasion of Afghanistan, which prompted the end of a period in which registration was not required.  See also https://www.sss.gov.  LPRs are also required to register.

Comment: Franck: (b) should indeed be an answer, because it is incorrect and comments cannot be downvoted.

Comment: In the case of dual Nationalities, the country you are presently in takes priority according to international conventions. If both countries accept the legitimacy of the dual nationality, then *in theory* they should respect the citizens responsibility to the other country. A child born of parents that had french and US citizenship at he time of their birth should fullfill this condition. Then, *in theory*, when drafted by the country of residence the other country should respect this. In how so far this is implemented in the corresponding draft laws would have to be determined.

Comment: This question belongs to [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica France has been involved in active combat operations almost without interruption since WWII. Barkhane has been going on since 2014 and now involves over 5000 troops, that's 10% of the French Army combat units (force Scorpion). Army soldiers in units liable to be deployed in Africa (i.e. not heavy armor) serve a 4-month tour of duty there every one or two-years or so, leaving just enough time for training, rest, preparation and other missions. France is not a very large country, all that is a bit more than an “occasional“ foray into Africa.

Comment: That said, I agree with you that any answer would be highly speculative. While the draft is formally “suspended” and still exists, the decision to use it again would involve passing a new law and would be so momentous that its parameters are likely to be redefined then and there.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the correction. Upon more research, there is indeed significant authority and organization remaining of the US' Selective Service System. Given the no-downvote aspect of Comments, and because my original issue (that the question is inappropriate here) still pends, I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @Relaxed agiven nd with the state of the US draft being similar (although I think that an executive order would be sufficient to resume active induction), the chance of both countries reinstating a draft and both drafting any one individual seems exceedingly remote indeed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, What if the two countries in questions are at war with each other?

Comment: @ouflak As is often the case in 'International Laws' there are no clear cut solutions to such problems and is often individualy desided by each country arbitrarily. State Department papers show that Switzerland often complained about the US drafting Swiss citizens, who were US residents, during WW2. (How this was resolved was not meantioned.)